# How to receive packets sent to ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

Tags: networking

I'm currently working on a project that will transmit and receive a message. I have separate codes for the transmitter and receiver, which I both run on the same PC. The transmitter transmits using the loopback interface. The packet is sent to the broadcast address (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff). Unfortunately, I'm still unable to receive the message successfully with my current receiver code. Is it correct to assume that I should be able to receive the message by listening to the loopback interface or any interface at the receiver side? I'm not sure about how to receive a message that is sent to the broadcast address. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: It looks like you want something with a MAC address, which is a layer-2 address for _some_ (IEEE) layer-2 protocols, like ethernet, token ring, Wi-Fi, etc. Some protocols that use MAC addressing use 48-bit MAC addresses (what you want), and some use 64-bit MAC addresses. Many layer-2 protocols do not use MAC addressing (frame relay uses DLCI, ATM uses VPI/VCI, PPP uses nothing, etc.). What layer-2 protocol do you think your loopback interface uses?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your explanation. After looking at Wireshark, I could see that ethernet is being used. The source is 00:00:00:00:00:00 and the destination is ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, which is the expected behavior of the transmitter code. To be able to receive this packet, do I need to also use the loopback interface? Do all interfaces (including loobpack) receive packets sent to the broadcast address? Thank you.